# ADF DataFlow toFloat function

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have try to use ADF dataflow to convert a column with data like '630.180004119873' to float data type using toFlaot() function, however when output i can see the data been converted to '630.18'.

Is there anyone have idea how to prevent ADF DataFlow toFloat function to keep the result as '630.180004119873' instead of converted to '630.18'?

The code are as below:
[ADF Derived Column Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgkh6.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "truncate to double only"? What is the result you are seeking? If you want a double, then you could use the toDouble function instead of toFloat.

Comment: @JoelCochran Thanks for comment. I been edit my question

Comment: Hello @weehongngeo , If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @weehongngeo, if you have any other concerns, please let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we can't use `toFloat` do the conversion. You could use [toDouble](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#todouble) 
 or [toDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#todecimal):
[image]

For example:

**toDecimal:** you can customize the precision and scale.
[image]

**toDouble:**
[image]

Hope this helps.